# How can I target the inner html of each cell in a table row that I've clicked on?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a function on my website so that users can click a "save" button on a particular row of this table that will pull up the innerHtml of the entire row element that they have selected and then Im going to put that info into another page for them as their saved hiking trails.

I have been trying to do this by adding click event listeners to the tables and then accessing the information of the table row through the target.

Does anyone know how I can access the inner html of the whole row and not just the cell that the save button is in?

Here is my html:

```html
<table class="table">
            <tr>
              <th>Trails</th>
              <th>Province</th>
              <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Lion's Head</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button id="save" class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Pipe Track</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button id="save" class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Skeleton Gorge</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button id="save" class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Table Mountain</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button id="save" class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">King Fisher Trail</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button id="save" button class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Robberg Peninsula</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button id="save" class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Diep Walle Forest Walk</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button id="save" class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

And here is the javascript that I have tried to use to target the row that I need.

```js
const save = document.querySelector(".save");
console.log(save);

save.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let row = document.getElementsByClassName("tableRow");
  console.log(row[1], row[2], row[3]);
});
```

This javascript is not targeting the right table cells.

Comment: Inside the event listener (once you have set all the listeners up correctly) you can use `e.target` to get a reference to the button that was clicked.  From there you can get the parentNode to get the td, and then parentNode again to get the tr.  `let myTR = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;`  Then you can do stuff with the innerHTML of myTR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have more than one element in your page with `id="save"` - **id must be unique at all times, per-document**. For multiple elements, use a class instead.

That being said, use [`event.target.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to find the row from a delegate listener (that is, you install the click listener on an ancestor element and capitalize on the bubbling mechanism of events). This way you also only need **one** listener.

```js
const table = document.getElementById('myTable');

table.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target.matches('button.save')) {
    const row = event.target.closest('tr');
    console.log(row.innerText);
  }
});
```

```html
<table class="table" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Trails</th>
      <th>Province</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tableRow">Lion's Head</td>
      <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
      <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button class="save">Save</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tableRow">Pipe Track</td>
      <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
      <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button class="save">Save</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tableRow">Skeleton Gorge</td>
      <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
      <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button class="save">Save</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tableRow">Table Mountain</td>
      <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
      <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button class="save">Save</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tableRow">King Fisher Trail</td>
      <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
      <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button button class="save">Save</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tableRow">Robberg Peninsula</td>
      <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
      <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button class="save">Save</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tableRow">Diep Walle Forest Walk</td>
      <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
      <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button class="save">Save</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't give same id's to different elements in DOM but you can create your custom attributes. I created `button-id` for each button. Then used it to get the row that is clicked.

```js
const save = document.querySelectorAll(".save"); // select all the buttons
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr") // select all the rows

console.log(rows)


save.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let id = e.target.getAttribute('button-id') // get the clicked buttons id
    console.log(id)
    console.log(rows[id]) // with id select the row
  });
})
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Trails</th>
    <th>Province</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableRow">Lion's Head</td>
    <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
    <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button button-id="1" class="save">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableRow">Pipe Track</td>
    <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
    <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button button-id="2" class="save">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableRow">Skeleton Gorge</td>
    <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
    <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button button-id="3" class="save">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableRow">Table Mountain</td>
    <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
    <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button button-id="4" class="save">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableRow">King Fisher Trail</td>
    <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
    <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button button-id="5" button class="save">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableRow">Robberg Peninsula</td>
    <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
    <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button button-id="6" class="save">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableRow">Diep Walle Forest Walk</td>
    <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
    <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button button-id="7" class="save">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to assign the eventListener to all save buttons. After trigger by a click you have access to it by using the event.target function. Then you can go upwards to the parent element `tr`. Afterwards you can handle the tr element.

**Note** It would be better to use `event.target.closest('tr')` to avoid some collisions in the future. If same changes in the code will come. *See the comment from @connexo*

```js
const save = document.querySelectorAll(".save");

save.forEach(s => {
  s.addEventListener("click", (e) => {    
    const row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.classList.toggle('border');
    console.log(row)
    //
  });
});
```

```css
.border {
  background: red;  
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
            <tr>
              <th>Trails</th>
              <th>Province</th>
              <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Lion's Head</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button id="save" class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Pipe Track</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button id="save" class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Skeleton Gorge</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button id="save" class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Table Mountain</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button id="save" class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">King Fisher Trail</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button id="save" button class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Robberg Peninsula</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button id="save" class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Diep Walle Forest Walk</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button id="save" class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: Use `event.target.closest('tr')` to find the row. Otherwise wrapping the `button` in a `span` will make your code fail (always a good idea to decouple things as much as possible). Also you need only a single, delegate listener on the `table`. Last thing, OP has multiple duplicate `id`s in their code (which also made it into your answer). `id` must be unique per-document.